# Align a button with an editText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button, android-relativelayout

I want to align a Button with an EditText. 
More precisely, i want to align the button with **id**= signinButton with the edittext
with **id**= passwordEditText.  The editText has **padding**  = "8dp". I suppose the button is aligned according to padding.
The layout file is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/nitos_background_color"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >




         <EditText
              android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="text" 
              android:hint="@string/username"
              android:background="#ffffff">
         <requestFocus />
        </EditText>





           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@+id/usernameEditText"
               android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
               android:padding="8dp"
               android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usernameEditText"
               android:ems="10"
               android:inputType="textPassword" 
               android:hint="@string/password"
               android:background="@color/white_background"/>

               <Button
                android:id="@+id/signinButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/passwordEditText"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordEditText"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordEditText"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="@string/signin" />

             <CheckBox 
                 android:id="@+id/keep_me_signed_in_checkbox"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/signinButton"
                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/signinButton"
                 android:text="@string/keep_me_signed_in"
                 style="@style/CustomFontStyleText"
                 android:textSize="@dimen/checkbox_text_size"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

**The final screen is:**

[image]

As you can see, the button is not perfectly aligned with the above EditText.

Comment: Use Linearlayout for this kind of design.

Comment: i think it is because of marginRight and Left you set in editText but not on Button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

That's default **Android** `Button` background that's why it displayed like that you can set *custom background* same like `EditText` to `Button`

```
android:background="@color/white_background"
```

That will display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because default button background style has inner paddings (transparent areas). Frames of these views are aligned correctly, but visually there are differences. To fix this you can set `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginRight` attributes of the button to slightly negative values, say `-5dp` and compare. Or assign a custom button background with no transparent areas around.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using linearLayout as pratik mentioned in comment.
Solution:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/nitos_background_color" >

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp" > 


        <EditText
              android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="text" 
              android:hint="@string/username"
              android:background="#ffffff">

           </EditText>


             <EditText
               android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
               android:padding="8dp"
               android:ems="10"
               android:inputType="textPassword" 
               android:hint="@string/password"
               android:background="@color/white_background"/>

               <Button
                android:id="@+id/signinButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:background="@color/light_blue_color"
                android:text="@string/signin" />

              <CheckBox 
                 android:id="@+id/keep_me_signed_in_checkbox"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/keep_me_signed_in"
                 style="@style/CustomFontStyleText"
                 android:textSize="@dimen/checkbox_text_size"/>



           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/nitlabImageView"
               android:layout_width="230dp"
               android:layout_height="200dp"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
               android:contentDescription="@string/nitlab_image"
               android:src="@drawable/nitlab_letters" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The final screen is:

[image]